# How to assign an id / className / refs to an input box and then call it in a variable using React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, variables

i am a React beginner and i am just starting to learn React.This is my first project that i am working on, it's an expense tracker. I am almost complete but there's one thing that i can't get my head around which is: how do you use id and classNames in react?. I have tried using refs but that gives me an error. **I just want to assign a id to the price input box and then call it in a variable without any errors**. Can someone help me with this? **MY CODE:**

```
import React from 'react';
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  var income = prompt("What is your income")
  var incometxt = income
  var price = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.price).value
  var expenses = 0
  function btnfunc() {
  expenses = +price + +expenses
   console.log(expenses, price)
  }

return(
<>
<div>
  <h1>Income:</h1><h1>{incometxt}</h1>
  <h1>Expense:</h1><h1>{expenses}</h1>
</div>
    <div>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Expense price" ref="price"></input>
      <button onClick={btnfunc}>Click me</button>
    </div>
</> 

)
}
export default App;
```

Comment: In this case you should use the main concept of REACT witch is 'state'
    https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to achieve what you're trying, is with the `useState` hook:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  var income = prompt("What is your income");
  var incometxt = income;

  const [price, setPrice] = useState(null);

  var expenses = 0;
  function btnfunc() {
    expenses = +price + +expenses;
    console.log(expenses, price);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>Income:</h1>
        <h1>{incometxt}</h1>
        <h1>Expense:</h1>
        <h1>{expenses}</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Expense price" value={price} onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={btnfunc}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer a question but I would recomment doing it with state like this

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState()
  var income = prompt("What is your income")
  var incometxt = income
  var expenses = 0
  function btnfunc() {
  expenses = +price + +expenses
   console.log(expenses, price)
  }

return(
      <input 
         type="number" 
         placeholder="Expense price" 
         value={price} 
         onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
       />

)
}
export default App;
```